# Build both release/debug VS2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build

Why do you have to build under release configuration, followed by another build of same project in debug configuration in VS2010 C++ to be able to have the debug see updated code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to. You only have to build the configurations which you want updated. That is, if you change your code and want to have Debug "see" the updated code, just build Debug. You don't have to build Release.

Of course, then your Release build will not "see" the new code until you build it again.

If you're asking why they have to be built separately - because the code generated by each of these settings is fundamentally different, so there's now way to "reuse" it somehow.

Comment: not very familiar with c++ build process, but for the project at hand, the debug build will not update code for the debug, until i do release build first

Comment: @SamAdams That's just weird. I don't know PBRT, so I don't know whether it does something *really crazy* in its build, but I can't think of a cause for this behaviour. Does it happen in other projects as well?

Comment: no just pbrt, its probably something with the multiple projects in one solution, or the solution file.

Comment: @SamAdams And if you just create a fresh solution (let's say with two projects)? Could it be an issue with your VS in general?

Comment: @Angnew thanks for the troubleshooting tips, yea that is the problem. How would i fix that?

Comment: @SamAdams I'm no VS expert, sorry. I'd consider a reinstall.

Answer (score 4):

Because each build links to different core libraries, uses different compiler/linker settings, creates different assembly code, and hence different executables, the release one probably more optimized. Btw there is a `Batch Build` menu item under the `Build` menu allowing to build everything with one click.

Comment: I don't think this is what he's asking - he seems to think that you need to do a release build *before* you can do a debug build.

Comment: Although, admittedly, it is ambiguous, so I can see how your answer could apply.

Comment: @stijn : Apparently, Batch Build might not work as expected: see http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/vs2008-debugrelease-configuration-27156.aspx - a multi-project solution will only include the currently-active-configuration version of its Library projects (dll's).